# Nuxt, 'Vue draggable'. Method "clone" has already been defined as a prop

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, draggable

using Nuxt (Vue 2).
I just put this code in my .vue file,

```
<draggable></draggable>
```

there is an error : [Vue warn]: Method "clone" has already been defined as a prop.

I already installed vuedraggable 2.24.1

In my plugins/vuedraggable.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'

Vue.component('draggable', draggable)
```

And my nuxt.config.js

```
{src: '~/plugins/vuedraggable'}
```

Any help? :(

Comment: [Vue warn] If am I true it isn't an error it's only a warning and the project can build with it !

am I true ?

Comment: @soroush Yes, It just a warning. but I want to remove this msg... annoying